# How to use a parameter of the function outside the function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a function which takes in an image from the Camera and processes the image and finally calculates the number of objects detected in the image along with the diameters. I want to check outside the function if the number of objects is 1 or not, and accordingly program to change the value of the signals which are producing the droplet(object).

```
def DropletRecognition(image_orig,image_calibration,Mean_section_brightness,line_lowerNozzleEdge):
showImages=1
#To maintain the brightness 
mean_brightness=np.mean(np.mean(image_orig[0:line_lowerNozzleEdge][:]))
factor=Mean_section_brightness/mean_brightness
image_orig = misc.imread(image_name)
image=image_orig*factor
image=image_orig
if showImages == 1:
    print('measured image')
    print(image_orig)
    print('image_calibration')
    print(image_calibration)
    fig1 = plt.figure(1)
    fig1.suptitle(image_name)
    plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
    plt.draw()
    plt.waitforbuttonpress()

#To subtract the calibration image from the measured image
image_subtracted = image-image_calibration

#Calculating the lower nozzle edge and doing further resizing
image_subtracted[0:line_lowerNozzleEdge][:]=0

#To delete the nozzle lines
image_subtracted=image_subtracted[line_lowerNozzleEdge+10:][:]
image_subtracted=image_subtracted.astype('uint32')

#Erosion and Dilation to condition the image
image_tmp=image_subtracted
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)

image_tmp = ndimage.grey_erosion(image_tmp, size=(6,6))
image_tmp = ndimage.grey_dilation(image_tmp, size=(6,6))
image_subtracted=image_tmp

#To convert the image to Binary
thresh_rc = mh.thresholding.rc(image_subtracted) 
thresh=thresh_rc
image_binary = image_subtracted > thresh
image_bin_int=image_binary.astype('uint8')

#To extract the features from the Binary Image
image_tmp=image_bin_int
im_floodfill = image_tmp.copy()
h, w = image_tmp.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((h+2, w+2), np.uint8)
cv2.floodFill(im_floodfill, mask, (0,0), 255);
im_floodfill_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(im_floodfill)
im_out = image_tmp | im_floodfill_inv
image_extracted=im_out

#To count the number of objects found in the image
T = mh.thresholding.otsu(image_extracted.astype('uint8'))
labeled,nr_objects = mh.label(image_extracted.astype('uint8') > T)
print(nr_objects)
print('number of detected objects = '+str(nr_objects))
label_array=np.array(labeled).ravel()
label_array=np.sort(label_array)
pixel_sum=np.zeros(nr_objects+1)
for ii in range(1,nr_objects+1,1): 
    n_tmp=np.where(label_array==ii)[0]
    pixel_sum[ii]=len(n_tmp)

#To calculate the Object Diameter using pixel sum and area
ObjectArea=pixel_sum*pixelArea

#Assuming that the object is a circle
Radius=np.sqrt(ObjectArea/np.pi)
Diameter=2*Radius
print(' ')
print('object diameters in um =',Diameter/1e-8)
print(' ')
print(' ')
if showImages == 1:
    fig2 = plt.figure(2)
    plt.clf()
    plt.imshow(labeled)
    plt.draw()
    plt.waitforbuttonpress()
return nr_objects
```

This is the function and I have to check outside the function like

```
if nr_objects == 1:
    break
elif nr_objects > 1:
    voltage +=80
else:
    voltage-=80
```

But this is not working. The program is not checking these if loops at all. I also checked normally like 
    if nr_objects == 1:
       print('Yes')
Even this is not working. So i can see that the parameter is not being accessed. Could anyone guide me how to do this??

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Calling the function `nr_objects = DropletRecognition(...)` and then checking `nr_objects` is not what you want? Also is the content of the function important other than it returns `nr_objects`? (If not, it's recommended to keep the example as minimal as possible)

Comment: I have tried it the same way as u have said above! May be i ll post here the exact one. It doesn't seem to be working.                                                   for n in range(1,2000):
 print(voltage)
 for t in range(1,20):
  control.drop.send1(control.ser,t,voltage)
 time.sleep(0.5)
 nr_objects = DropletRecognition(image,image_calibration,Mean_section_brightness,line_lowerNozzleEdge)
 time.sleep(10)
 print(nr_objects)
 if nr_objects == 1:
  break
 elif nr_objects > 1:
  voltage +=80
 else:
  voltage-=80

Comment: You should put the code that you pasted in your original question with the exact indentation in your code. Your problem might be that `break` only breaks the inner loop, while the outer loop is still going.

Comment: You said somehow that the program is not checking these if-loops. Does it print out `nr_objects` from the line `print(nr_objects)` that you have in the code?

Comment: no it doesn't print. that's why i thought its not checking if loops.

Comment: Note you have `print(nr_objects)` before the if loop. And you're saying it doesn't print after 10 seconds (considering that you have `time.sleep(10)`)?

Answer (score 1):

The variable you need to test for is not necesarily `nr_objects`. It's whatever appears to the left of the call to the function. i.e.

```
test_me = DropletRecognition(... your arguments here)

if test_me == 1:
    break
elif test_me > 1:
    voltage +=80
else:
    voltage-=80
```